# How to properly Drape vectors over a DEM?

Tags: 3d, visualisation, arcscene

I have a DEM of my study area, and the streams in it. 
Whenever I add both to ArcScene, and drape the vectors over the DEM, some of the vectors disappear from over the surface, and are visible **under** the surface. (see Image below).
[image]

Are there any specific settings to properly drape the vectors over the DEM?
Are there any other options or software that produce a better result (visually) when you have to drape vectors over a DEM?

Answer (score 7):

I have made ​​the experience that the problem can not always be solved completely. But if you use layer's drawing priority, it gets better. Please try to use the [layer's drawing priority](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00q80000006v000000):

> In ArcScene you can change the drawing priority of each of the layers
>   being displayed, so the more important layers will render on top of
>   the less important layers. Using the 3D Effects toolbar you can change
>   this property quickly. Steps:
>
> - On the 3D Effects toolbar, click the Layer drop-down arrow and choose the layer you want to change the draw order for.
> - Click the Change Depth Priority Change Depth Priority button and move the slider to a value.
>
> In the numeric scale for depth priority, 1 is the highest and 10 is
>   the lowest. If you want to decrease priority, choose a higher number.

Answer (score 3):

How did you drape the vectors? I think you need to [set the Base Heights](http://www.brocku.ca/maplibrary/procedures/3d_view/3dview.htm). To do so:

> - Right click the vector data layer and select Properties.
> - Click the Base Heights tab.
> - Select the radial button beside Obtain heights for layer from surface. The program automatically selects the DEM open in ArcScene.
> - Click Apply, then move to the Extrusion tab.

[image]

> - Put a check in the box beside Extrude features in layer and change the extrusion value to 2 or 3. Test different values to see the
>     changes on the map.
> - Click Apply to view the changes or OK to return to the ArcScene map window.

[image]

Hopefully, that'll do the trick :)

Another option would be to use the [Virtual Terrain project](http://vterrain.org/). It's an open source 3D visualization tool.

> The goal of VTP is to foster the creation of tools for easily
>   constructing any part of the real world in interactive, 3D digital
>   form.
>
> This goal will require a synergetic convergence of the fields of CAD,
>   GIS, visual simulation, surveying and remote sensing.  VTP gathers
>   information and tracks progress in areas such as procedural scene
>   construction, feature extraction, and rendering algorithms.  VTP
>   writes and supports a set of software tools, including an interactive
>   runtime environment (VTP Enviro).  The tools and their source code are
>   freely shared to help accelerate the adoption and development of the
>   necessary technologies.

[image]

They have a nice [tutorial page](http://vterrain.org/Doc/). Good luck :)

Comment: I have tried using the Extrusion; If it is too small, then some features still disappear, and if it is large, then you can see the extrusion, thus making it feel unnatural.

Comment: You've set the Base Heights too?

Answer (score 0):

Another option would be to convert the vectors to 3D lines, using the DEM as a base height. This willake the lines "extrude" automatically and will be at the height above the DEM. I have experienced this issue before and it's very frustrating. If you are soley looking for a visual fix, you can apply a floating value to the extrusion and the lines will float above the DEM, not ideal, but will work.